# What is the main difference between JavaEE @PreDestroy vs HttpSessionListener#sessionDestroyed and when to use what?

Tags: jakarta-ee, session-timeout

I had a requirement to lock and release a resource upon user editing it. 
I can easily set a lock on it and when user saves it unlock it or when user log out do the unlocking.

But my problem is when the user goes to edit page and just leave it there without saving or just close the browser while in the edit page. 
In this case I have to unlock the resource for other users to access.

The resource is not heavily in demand. So can wait until session timeout and unlock it. So I found these two ways to do it. 
1. Use "@PreDestroy" annotation to call a method that will unlock the resource.
2. Implement "HttpSessionListener" and write the unlocking logic inside "HttpSessionListener#sessionDestroyed"

But for me it seems both doing the same. 
Can you guys please let me now which one is better for my scenario and the main difference between these two?

Using JAVA 7, EJB3 and JSF2
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I did some research with these two methods and came to a conclusion.

The @PreDestroy annotated method is internally handled by the HttpSessionListener#sessionDestroyed.

The first point to hit is HttpSessionListener#sessionDestroyed then the @PreDestroy annotated method will be called. So I decided to go with HttpSessionListener#sessionDestroyed. Below is my implementation.

```
@WebListener
public class MyHttpSessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

    Logger logger = new Logger();

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent arg0) {
        // Nothing to DO
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent arg0) {
        try {
            HttpSession session = arg0.getSession();
            Object sessionMyObj = session.getAttribute("myDTBManagedBean");

            if (sessionMyObj != null && sessionMyObj instanceof MyDTBManagedBean) {
                MyDTBManagedBean myDTB = (MyDTBManagedBean ) sessionMyObj;

                if (myDTB != null) {
                   //Do my unlocking logic
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(//log exception);
    }
}
```

The @WebListener makes the class as servlet listener
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebListener.html